# Running Eclipse configuration from the console

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, xtext

I am trying to run the `xtend` Server (ServerLaucher.xtend) as a Java Application. It works if I execute it in eclipse. If I open the Run Configuration, click on Show Command Line, copy the code from it (which looks like this one)

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 
...
mydsl.web.ServerLauncher`

and run it in a normal terminal, the server starts as normal and says that it is available under `localhost:8080`. The problem, however, is that, in contrast to running it in Eclipse, the website doesn't work and I got the error website:

```
HTTP ERROR 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:
Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://...
```

Comment: check the classpath, it may contain relative paths so you need to run the command from the correct directory.

Comment: are you sure you execute the command from withing the mydsl.web folder as eclipse does it?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I do not have to. I just want to run it from the console. If you know another way please tell me.

Comment: As said. Go to the mydsl.web dir and run it there. Or read the jetty docs how to pass the . dir as param and adapt the class